# Volume and lateral surface area are equal

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to express the radius $r$ of the right circular cone as a function of its height $h$  given that its volume equals to its lateral surface area.  I know the two equations $\pi r \times \sqrt{r^2 + h^2}$ and the volume $\frac{\pi}{3} r^2 h$.  Do I just set these equations as equal and solve for $h$?  I'm not quite sure where to go from here.

Comment: You did not state which geometrical object you deal with... If you need to find $r(h)$, you should be solving for $r$, rather than $h$.

Comment: Sorry, this is a right circular cone.

Comment: $\sqrt{r^2+h^2}=\frac{1}{3}rh$ , square both sides and solve for $r$

Comment: @erimar77 I have edited your question to state the geometric object under consideration as well as to include the constraint. If you agree with the changes, please remove `*[added]*` and `*[/added]*` from the text.

Comment: Am I the only one who really dislikes this question (as homework)?  Maybe it's the physicist in me, but volume and area are different _notions_, and equating the two is inherently unit-dependent in a painfully ungeometric way.  I appreciate the need to introduce algebraic questions in some fashion, but surely that can be done in a way at least somewhat less arbitrary than this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lateral surface area is $A_L = \frac{1}{2} C \times S$, where $C$ is the base circumference, and $S = \sqrt{r^2+h^2}$ is the distance from the tip of the cone to the point on the base circle.

Equality of the volume and the surface area gives you an equation:
$$
   \pi r \sqrt{r^2+h^2} = \frac{\pi}{3} r^2 h
$$
Assuming $r>0$ and $h>0$, this simplifies to $3 \sqrt{r^2+h^2} = r h$. Squaring the left-hand-side and the right-hand-side will give the auxiliary equation, with the property that every solution of the original equation being a solution of the auxiliary equation. But the auxiliary equation might have extraneous solutions.

The auxiliary equation will be a simple quadratic equation, with two solutions. You should check which one of these will satisfy the original equation, and under which conditions this will be possible.